# How can I add a web browser address bar to lxpanel?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, panel, url, lxpanel

Do you know if there is any way I can add the Firefox address bar to Lubuntu's panels? Or a widget, I don't know. I don't want to disappear with Firefox's bar, just want to open the browser by typing a link or search in my desktop.

Comment: Please clarify the problem that needs to be addressed / goal to be achieved in your question.

Comment: would it be enough with the 'Run box', started with `Alt` + `F2`: type `firefox askubuntu.com` (or some other web address).